# How to process/update arrays in loop that calls firebase to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm having issues trying to do some data processing while looping over some records from a firebase call. Within the loop, I'm making a firebase call to retrieve data, which I then want to use to update an element in the object array. I've provided a simplified version of the method below which exhibits the issue.

In this example, I want to insert new values into an array if they don't exist, then make a call to firebase to retrieve new data, the update the array elements.

Finally, I simply do a console.log to loop over the new array that should have been created to output new values.  However, when the code runs, nothing is displayed, as if the array isn't created yet.

If I simply do `console.log(newArray)` it shows the elements with the data.

But my issue is, I need to process those elements in the `newArray` further...and it doesn't exist at that point in code.

I've tried wrapping the entire loop in a `Promise.all[]` call, and using the `.then()` method to loop over the `newArray` elements, but that didn't work.

This seems like it should be easy, but I'm missing something that must be related to the async response from firebase.

```js
TestArrayUpdates = () => {
    namestoInsert = [
        { name: 'Bob', score: 5 },
        { name: 'Jim', score: 10 },
        { name: 'steve', score: 15 }
    ];

    newArray = [];
    let dayscore = 0;

    namestoInsert.map((el, i) => {
        let idx = newArray.findIndex(item => item.name == el.name);
        if (idx == -1) {
            firebase
                .database()
                .ref('userscoresbyday')
                .child('2019-Aug-30')
                .child('bgmd0r5HyZViLQZBynXUSm9e9Ab2')
                .once('value', snap => {
                    if (snap.exists()) {
                        dayscore = snap.val().score;
                    }
                })
                .then(() => {
                    newscore = el.score + dayscore;
                    newArray.push({ name: el.name, score: newscore });
                });
        }
    });

    newArray.map((el, i) => {
        console.log(el.name);
    });
};
```

I expected the output to be list of names. Nothing is displayed.

Comment: You need to collect all the promises you are creating and then await them using `Promise.all`.

Comment: Welcome to asynchronous programming, btw. Does my comment help you or would you need an example?

Comment: Could you provide a quick example with the code I provided? I've used promises before, but not a lot..

Comment: **TYPO** alert: it's **retrieve** - not "retreive" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly diagnosed yourself, you need to wait for all the stuff you're doing to be done, before you can output anything. The way to do that is by actually waiting for the promises you are creating. The following code should do that in theory. I can't fully test it as I have no access to that `firebase` thing, but I am using a mockup.

```
FetchScore = (el) => new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("Now asking database");
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref('userscoresbyday')
        .child( '2019-Aug-30' )
        .child( 'bgmd0r5HyZViLQZBynXUSm9e9Ab2' ).
        .once('value', snap => {
            console.log("The database answered");
            if( snap.exists() )
            {
                console.log("Found a score");
                resolve( snap.val().score );
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("No points!");
                resolve( 0 );
            }
        });

    console.log("Done asking database");
});


TestArrayUpdates = ( namestoInsert ) => {
    newArray = [];

    console.log("Allright, here we go");
    promises = namestoInsert.map( (el,i) => {
        console.log("Here comes: " + el.name);

        if( newArray.find(item => item.name == el.name) )
        {
          console.log("Skipping, I've seen them before");
            return Promise.resolve(-1);
        }

        console.log(el.name + " is new in town!");

        // then also returns a Promise
        return FetchScore(el).then( (score) => {
            if ( newArray.find( item => item.name == el.name ) )
            {
                console.log("Do nothing, we have already registered " + el.name);
            }
            else  
            {
                console.log("Registering score for " + el.name);
                newArray.push({'name': el.name, 'score': el.score + score })
            }
        });
    });

    console.log("All questions asked, waiting for " + promises.length + " answers.");
    // Let's wait for all the promises to be kept
    return Promise.all(promises).then( () => {
        console.log("Here are our answers:");
        // and then we output our stuff
        newArray.map((el,i) => {
            console.log(el.name + " = " + el.score);
        })
        console.log("We're done");
    });

    console.log("Everything is set up");

}
console.log("Am I really ...");
TestArrayUpdates( [{name: 'Bob', score: 5}, {name: 'Jim', score:10}, {name:'Steve', score:15}, {name:'Bob', score:15}] );
console.log("... already here????");
```

This produces the following output:

```
> Am I really ...
> Allright, here we go
> Here comes: Bob
> Bob is new in town!
> Now asking database about Bob
> Here comes: Jim
> Jim is new in town!
> Now asking database about Jim
> Here comes: Steve
> Steve is new in town!
> Now asking database about Steve
> Here comes: Bob
> Bob is new in town!
> Now asking database about Bob
> All questions asked, waiting for 4 answers.
> ... already here????
> The database answered
> Registering score for Bob
> The database answered
> Registering score for Jim
> The database answered
> Registering score for Steve
> The database answered
> Do nothing, we have already registered Bob
> Here are our answers:
> Bob = 16
> Jim = 21
> Steve = 26
> We're done
```

I hope this helps to wrap your head around what happens when.

Comment: Thank you! Worked great...I just didn't have my promise logic set up correctly, but the code above clarified it..thanks again.

Comment: One more follow up question. In my actual logic, I need to perform several DB lookups in the inner loop...and then at very end of that, I "push" the new item into the newarray (newArray.push({'name': el.name, 'score': newscore }). What's happening is that it appears the item doesn't get inserted fast enough, because it ends up inserting multiple of the same items. It's not clear to me how I ensure all logic + item is inserted before it continues with the outer loop? The only idea I had was to insert a skeleton item at top of logic, and then perform updates within the array, but seems wrong

Comment: If you have multiple queries you also have multiple promises you must wait for. You can just return a Promis.all(queries) from your function to do so. Stop thinking in 
 nested loops. Those and async don't mix well. If you're doing async and think "loop" what you want is usually `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled`.

Comment: i found a simple way to demonstrate my issue. In the above code, change the starting array to:  namestoInsert =[{name: 'Bob', score: 5}, {name: 'Jim', score:10}, {name:'steve', score:15},{name: 'Bob', score: 5},{name: 'Bob', score: 5},{name: 'Bob', score: 5}]; Basically, include a few duplicate "Bob". In my code, I only want Bob to appear once in the NewArray, but it appears for every iteration. How to solve?

Comment: Simply look into newArray and see if Bob already exists before you add him.`if ( !newArray.find( (e) => { return e.name == el.name } ) ) ...`

Comment: But wouldn't you rather want to add up the scores?

Comment: Isn't this check on the index the same thing? let idx = newArray.findIndex(item => item.name == el.name)

Comment: it's checking the newArray at the top, so it why doesn't it find the name? I should also mention, if you remove the firebase async stuff , then the check works correctly and it filters out those names.

Comment: Remember your code is asynchronous. The check at the top of the function and the adding within the closure are happening at different times and in different contexts. You also need to check, right before you add.

Comment: ok,, thx...this async processing is throwing me a bit...appreciate the responses.

Comment: I'm confused. `firebase.database().ref('userscoresbyday').child('2019-Aug-30').child('bgmd0r5HyZViLQZBynXUSm9e9Ab2')`seems to be returning the same for every item in your names list. I realize this is a mockup. Is the id in "reality" coming from your data too?

Comment: Anyway, please see my new revised answer, which takes all of this into account and contains strategic logging so you can follow the flow.